# datatable and ajax where the json data is deeply nested

Tags: javascript, html, datatable, datatables

How do I configure datatable to render this data correctly.

```
"date": "2021-02-08",
"title": "Venues",
"data": {
    "monitor": [
        {
            "Venue": "Headlands Hotel Austinmer Beach",
            "Address": "Headland Ave and Yuruga Street, Austimer, NSW 2515",
            "Suburb": "Austinmer",
            "Date": "Tuesday 2 February 2021",
            "Time": "1pm to 3pm"
        },
        {
            "Venue": "Bulli Beach Café ",
            "Address": "68 Trinity Row, Bulli, NSW 2516",
            "Suburb": "Bulli",
            "Date": "Saturday 6 February 2021",
            "Time": "1:30pm to 4pm"
        },
```

This is what I am currently using but does not work.

```
$('#locations').DataTable( {
    "ajax": url,
    "columns": [
        { "monitor": "Suburb" },
        { "monitor": "Venue" },
        { "monitor": "Address" }
    ]
} );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`dataSrc`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc) option to instruct DataTables where your data array is located inside the JSON response structure. This is where DataTables will begin its row-by-row iteration.

This requires a change to your `ajax` option:

```
"ajax": {
  "url": "your URL here",
  "dataSrc": "data.monitor"
}
```

Now you can refer to the relevant fields in your column definitions, using the `data` option:

```
"columns": [
  { "data": "Suburb" },
  { "data": "Venue" },
  { "data": "Address" }
]
```

Comment: Thank you, after re-reading the documentation, almost got there! But was missing the data.monitor in dataSrc.